# C#, sqlsever Popualar datagrid através de Pesquisa

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Pessoal estou com um dificuldade, para fazer uma chamada na minha procedure o parâmetro de é digitar o nome da pessoal e trazer o registro no grid.

Estou usando 3 camadas, DAL, DTO, BLL;

Pode me orientar ?
Como posso prosseguir ao digitar o nome da pessoa no textbox, fazer a pesquisar, através da procedure.

Todos exemplos que eu vi chamando do textbox, é na ação do click do botão.
Creio que não seria a melhor maneira.

Comment: porque você acha: `Todos exemplos que eu vi chamando do textbox, é na ação do click do botão. Creio que não seria a melhor maneira.` ???

Comment: Criei a conexão com o banco de dados através de uma classe dal, entendo que na ação do botão seja utilizado o método da classe dal.
Se puder me ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: se tinha que colocar o código que você fez o que está dando de errado, ou as duvidas desse código!

Comment: DLLnamespace SistemaLocadoraVeiculos.CODE.BLL
{
    public class ClienteBLL
    {
        ACessoDao bd = new ACessoDao();
        ClienteDTO dto = new ClienteDTO();

        public DataTable SelecionaReserva()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            bd.Conectar();            
            dt = bd.RetDataTable("exec ConsultaCliente " + "'"+dto.Nome+"'");        
            return dt;        
                           
        }
    }
  }